# Django : Using selected radio button's value in views to update value in database

Tags: django, sqlite, radio-button, django-queryset

I am trying to write a view where the selected radio button's value/id ( not sure ) will be passed to django view after clicking submit and then that value should be stored in a column for a particular user and the question to which the radio button held an answer.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

labels=[]
for i in range(1,16):
    labels.append('a'+str(i))

for label in labels:
    Profile.add_to_class(label, models.CharField(max_length=255, default='NULL', blank='NULL'))


class Image(models.Model):

    p_img = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='p_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    p_img_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    s_image1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image')
    s_image2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    s_image3 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    s_image4 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')
    s_image5 = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to='s_image',default='NULL', blank='NULL')


    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.p_image))




class Score(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.username)
```

**views.py**

```
def update_db(request):

    # getting selected radio button value and use to it update that particular user's answer in Profile model. 

    return render(request, index.html, {})
```

**index.html**

```
<form action='/update' >
<p style="background-color: #ddd674">Primary image :<img src="{{media_url}}{{ p_img.p_img }}" height=300px > <br> 
</p>
<hr height=2px >
<p style="background-color: #a7e0d9">Secondary image :


    {% for img in s_img %}
        {% if img  %}
            <input type="radio" id="{{ img }}" name="ans" >
                <img src="{{media_url}}{{ img }}" height=250px > 
            </input>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <br> 

</p>

    <button type="submit" name="next" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"> Next / Submit </button></h5>
  </form>
```

> My main concern is to get the query to get the selected radio button value in the view function and update it to that particular user.

Comment: I found out that to request the radio button value I can use `request.POST.get("ans")` , which was the issue. And `<input type="submit" value="Submit" > ` before the form ends to trigger the form action.

Answer (score 0):

You're completely missing a `Form` abstraction layer.

Please read that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/